# Pass req.user.username as a parameter to successRedirect in Passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

When a user logs in successfully, I want to redirect them to a route that takes their username as a parameter:

```
router.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard/" + req.user.username,
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  })
);
```

```
router.get("/dashboard/:username", checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("dashboard", { user: req.user });
});
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
successRedirect: "/dashboard/" + req.user.username,                                     
                                 ^
ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

(I understand why `req is not defined`, but I am showing this to illustrate what it is I want to do.)

I have tested around with changing the route to the following:

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.username);    // a test; prints what is expected
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard/" + req.body.username,
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  });
});
```

When I login with the details, `console.log(...)` works as expected and prints the user's name. However, the `successRedirect` does not works as it just keeps loading. There's no form of output in the console, either.

I then also tried `req.user.username` (in the most recent route), but it just prints:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

To finally add, when I `console.log(req.body)`, I get:

```
[Object: null prototype] { username: 'user1', password: 'user1' }
```

Is there something I am not understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution (pretty quickly after writing this post). I think it's worth noting, still, in case others are in this position.

```
router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  }),(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/dashboard/" + req.user.username);
  }
);
```

I ommitted `successRedirect`, as a successful login will run the route function anyway; all you have to do is account for the failed login attempts (i.e. `failureRedirect`, or handle a `401` status code), as you can redirect the user with the `req.user` now existing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quoting documentation here:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

`passport.authenticate('local')` is acting as a middleware and will call the next function that can access the Req object.

Comment: Yeah, I literally just came across this. Thank you anywya